# Is there a better way to do these mySql updates?

Tags: mysql

```
    executeSQL("UPDATE records SET played = played + 1 WHERE player IN " + generateClause(all));
    executeSQL("UPDATE records SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE player IN " + generateClause(r.getWinners()));
    executeSQL("UPDATE records SET winrate = ((wins/played) * 1000) WHERE player IN " + generateClause(all));
```

Basically i'm trying to update the records of the players after a match. My program works as expected but it seems to require 3 queries, i'd want to do just one if possible since i've figured out that less queries drastically reduces the runtime of the app, even if the modifications to the db are the same.

My queries are as follows...
1) increase the "played" count for all the players that have played
2) add a win for the players that have won
3) calculate the winrate for all players that have just played

any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CASE statement to manage the `wins` incrementing players and the WHERE statement to increment everyone else:

```
executeSQL = "UPDATE records SET played = played + 1, wins = wins + CASE WHEN player in " + generateClause(r.getWinners) + " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, winrate = ((wins/played) * 1000) WHERE  player in " + generateClause(all))
```

Comment: I'm assuming the middle generateClause(all) should be generateClause(r.getWinners)? I tried that and doesn't work, doesn't seem to updated the played column for the losers

Comment: Yes. Sorry that should be `r.getWinners`. I can't imagine why the statement wouldn't work as-is. Can you shoot the SQL into a variable and insure that it's written correctly before execution?

Comment: Figured the issue out, your solution was correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that generateClause(all) contains all players, and the other one contains only the winners, right?...

I'd suggest this:

```
UPDATE ... SET wins = wins + player IN( list of winners ),
              played = played+1,
              winrate = 1000*(wins + player IN( list of winners ))/(played+1)
WHERE player IN (list of players)
```

I just checked: IN seems to be properly optimized here.

However, if you use a more recent version of MySQL, remember that you can create expression (ie, virtual) columns, and you could make winrate a virtual column. These can be indexed, too!

EDIT:

"seq" contains 1M rows.

```
SELECT sum(id) FROM seq
SELECT sum(id IN (list of 1000 numbers)) FROM seq
```

The difference in execution time is 0.3s, which means IN(1000 numbers) takes 0.3 µs, which means MySQL must use some form of hash to optimize it. So, don't worry about repeating your IN() three times... It will be fast.